# Отправка сообщений всем пользователям db

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

есть простенькая база с пользователями, которым нужно отправлять мессаджи

```
class Subscribe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    company = db.Column('company', db.String(50))
    email = db.Column('email', db.String(50))
```

Есть скрипт, который отправляет сообщение, в данном случае первому пользователю бд

```
@app.route('/sendmail', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    theuser = Subscribe.query.filter(Subscribe.id).first()
    msg = Message('Hello', sender='flask@mail.com', recipients=[theuser.email])

    with app.open_resource(r"C:\py\image.jpg") as fp:
        msg.attach("image.png", "image/png", fp.read())
    mail.send(msg)
    return 'Message sent!'
```

Подскажите, как отправить сообщение всем пользователям бд

Comment: `for theuser in Subscribe.query.all():`?

Comment: @gil9red Так просто, что даже стыдно за вопрос:) Но! теперь в связи с недостатком знаний, не могу получить список email. Создаю запрос к бд - theuser =Subscribe.query.filter_by(email='email').all() получаю пустой список [ ]

Comment: Да ладно вам :) А есть ли в `Subscribe` у поля `email` значение `"email"`? Попробуйте, например, через sql повторить его же: `select * from Subscribe where email = 'email'`

Comment: @gil9red Вы опять правы, данный запрос возвращает 0 строк. Просветите пожалуйста, как из данной базы выбрать все email адреса?

Comment: Вам нужно из таблицы Subscribe получить все email'ы? С sqlalchemy почти не работал но напрашивается такой код: `emails = [theuser.email for theuser in Subscribe.query.all()]`

Comment: @gil9red Вы мой спаситель, заработало!

Comment: Рад что вам это помогло. Собрал все из комментариев в ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы из таблицы `Subscribe` получить все записи, нужно вызвать `all`, например:

```
for theuser in Subscribe.query.all():
    ...
```

Чтобы из таблицы получить все `email`, то:

```
for theuser in Subscribe.query.all():
    print(theuser.email)
```

или в одну строку как список:

```
emails = [theuser.email for theuser in Subscribe.query.all()]
```

Comment: То, что нужно!!! единственный вопрос, не нашел в документации Flask-Mail  как скрыть адреса получателей

Comment: @Vadim, не знаю, лучше оформите это как отдельный вопрос и в метке укажите flask -- чтобы людям в теме проще было найти его. А так, откуда вы хотите скрыть адреса получателей?

Comment: @Vadim, я все гадаю что у вас происходит. Мб у вас получатели письма видят кому оно еще было отправлено? Тогда, думаю причина в том что все получатели указываются разом. И это легко обходится вот пример https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/#bulk-emails . Т.е. в цикле `for theuser in Subscribe.query.all():` повторите код из вопроса начиная от `msg = ...` и заканчивая `mail.send(msg)`. Тогда каждому подписчик получит индивидуальное письмо, а в `recipients` будет указан только один адрес -- текущего в итерации подписчика